# Trigger to insert row into another table if deleted

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I'm trying to create a trigger that will duplicate the ONE row that was deleted to another table. So far, I have just duplicated the whole first table into the second one when I deleted one row, not very useful.

Table1 is comment with comment_id, file_id, user_id, comment_text, comment_datetime and parent

Table2 is comment_log with deleted_comment_id, file_id, user_id, comment_text, comment_datetime and comment_deletion_datetime.

So I just want comments that have been deleted by a user, moderator or admin to be stored in comment_log.

```
INSERT INTO comment_log(deleted_comment_id, file_id, user_id, comment_text,comment_datetime, comment_deletion_datetime)
SELECT comment.comment_id, file_id, user_id, comment_text, comment_datetime, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM comment
```

This is where I've gotten so far, I have tried stuff like a WHERE behind, but I have no idea what to put there. old.comment_id should give me the old id, but I have no idea how to get just the comment with that id from the comment table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns of the row that is deleted are available in the trigger as `OLD.*`, so I'd do it this way:

```
INSERT INTO comment_log
SET deleted_comment_id = OLD.comment_id, 
    file_id = OLD.file_id, 
    user_id = OLD.user_id,
    comment_text = OLD.comment_text,
    comment_datetime = OLD.comment_datetime, 
    comment_deletion_datetime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Perfect, works just as intended! :D